Why does the suggested edit queue have a fixed size, and can we delete that list items?
Stack Exchange sites have a suggested edit queue, visible to the users who have the edit questions and answers privilege.

How to delete one for edit queue element


This question is similar to: Why does the suggested edit queue have a fixed size, and what is its size on each site?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As a reviewer, finishing a suggested edit by making it either approved or rejected would remove it from the queue. As a non-reviewer you can only work with your own suggestions but you cannot retract them. You can only change the suggestion to something different. See View edit review queue, remove own suggested edits from queue.

Hi Moon Princess, can you please explain your question in more detail? Are you asking about the amount of items in the Suggested Edit Review Queue? Since you're not mentioning the 'Skip' option, it seems you're not asking whether you can 'delete' (or skip) an item from the Suggested Edit review queue.

I have edited some answer and now it is fixed queue and now I'm not able to edit, so just i want to discard previous edited one,

The size of the suggest edit queue is fixed as not to flood the queue with an unreasonable amount of edits.
There are only so many reviews and if anyone could suggest anything the queue would be flooded with loads of minor (and arguably lower quality) edits. By restricting the amount of possible edits in total and five edits per user at a time (until you have 2000 reputation), users are supposed incentivized to make good use of their suggest-edit privilege and in theory should make less but better edit.
As for deleting your edit from the queue, I don't think that is possible. While you can choose to "roll back" to an older revision, that still counts as a suggest-edit. So all you can do is wait, depending on how niche the edited post is it takes somewhere between a few days and weeks for the suggest-edit to get processed.
